# View Actions not Redirecting to Port set on IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know how to set up the default port for the request/URL link.

Currently at work we first develop the application offline (using VS Development Server/IIS Express), then we publish to the file system and then finally grab all the files in the file system and transfer them to the IIS default dir, create the web application in the connection's tab using IIS Manager.

My problem is, for every action I'm defining an input button, every button almost equal to the following code snippet in my View's .aspx file.

```html
<input type="submit" name="btnExample" value="btnExample" id="btn-example-id" />
```

But after entering the view in the server's path (eg. serverpath:DEFAULT_PORT/appDir/Index) and executing the button, it doesn't redirect me to the link using the port (eg. serverpath:DEFAULT_PORT/appDir/btnExample), it redirects me without using the default server port (serverpath/appDir/btnExample), so I can't consume the view.

Comment: What URL are you returning for the redirect? (To answer this question we need to know enough of the server's implementation.) Also: ASP.NET WebForms or MVC? (For the former please update the question with the information, for the latter add the appropriate tag.)

Comment: I am currently using ASP .NET MVC. Although I'm not sure what you meant by "server's implementation", I'm currently using Windows Server 2008 implementation with IIS Manager. I think the default request methods are automatically handled by IIS, aren't they? I'm just looking for the method to set the default port - I have a hunch that I should put it on my Web.config.

Comment: To handle POST requests you'll need to write code on the server. GET will only work for a static resource (ie. there is a file to return) unless you write code. ASP.NET-MVC is a framework for writing that code in controllers that designate a view to be rendered, using data passed from the controller, and then sent to the client.

Comment: The web app running in an IIS app-pool is a container in which to execute that code.